# How do you pronounce "15g/kg"?

Tags: pronunciation

> Then 15g/kg ethyl alcohol diluted.

I don't know how to pronounce "15g/kg".

Comment: I think you're looking for **per**, as in "five grams **per** kilogram of ethyl alcohol".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Fifteen grams per kilogram" is the way to verbalise the sentence. "g/kg" is a unit comparing the number of grams of mass something has to the number of kilograms of mass something else has, and the slash indicates a ratio and corresponds to "per", "for every", "to", or any other common way to express a ratio.